# Showing a custom View on a list item view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

This might seem weird, but I'm trying to show a custom view I've made on a list view item.
My custom view draws keyboard chords and this work when I show them on a FragmentActivity, with
ViewPager, etc. I did as I had done before, created a XML file as a list item and implemented a class
extending from ArrayAdapter. When I inflate an XML file, it works just fine, but it's not working
when I use my custom view class, that doesn't have a xml file. Do you guys have any clue? My code is below. Thanks a lot :)

```
public class ShowChordActivityNew extends Activity {

    private ListView chordList;

    private List<KeyboardChordDiagram> aList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_chord_activity_new);

        chordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvChords);
        // this array is a chord I'm using to test this before moving to my working code
        int[] chord = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        aList = new ArrayList<KeyboardChordDiagram>();      
        aList.add(new KeyboardChordDiagram(getApplicationContext(), "A", chord));
        aList.add(new KeyboardChordDiagram(getApplicationContext(), "A", chord));
        aList.add(new KeyboardChordDiagram(getApplicationContext(), "A", chord));


        chordList.setAdapter(new MyAdpater());  
    }

    private class MyAdpater extends ArrayAdapter<KeyboardChordDiagram> {

        public MyAdpater() {
            super(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.fragment_list_item, aList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                //since my class extends View, this should work, right?
                KeyboardChordDiagram a = aList.get(position);       
                itemView = a;                   
            }

            return itemView;
        }

    }
}
```

//Here's my KeyboardChordDiagram class constructor
public class KeyboardChordDiagram extends ChordDiagram {
    .....

```
public KeyboardChordDiagram(Context context, String aChordName, int[] aChord) {
    super(context, aChordName);
    chord = aChord;
    .....
}

....
```

}

//Here's the ChordDiagram class:

public abstract class ChordDiagram extends View implements OnClickListener{

```
.....

public ChordDiagram(Context context, String aChordName) {
    super(context);
    .....
}
....
```

}

Comment: Please show the `KeyboardChordDiagram` class, or at least its constructor. You should be creating the new `KeyboardChordDiagram` inside the `getView` function. Your problem is that you're not establishing the parent/child relationship of the chord with the list.

Comment: I edited the question to add the construtor. I'm struggling to understand how I should bind the chord with the list. I tried to instantiate a KeyboardChordDiagram inside the getView() method, passing getContext() as parameter, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You havent binded the value to the views placed in your itemView . I think you need to bind the values from  the "a" object to the listview row. That is missing in getView